# Вызов частичного представления при запуске cshtml

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc

Проблемка такая:

Имеется *cshtml* с кодом страницы и *cshtml* с кодом всплывающего окна (частичное представление).

В данный момент всё работает через нажатие кнопки. Т. е. нажал — открылось окно.

Мне необходимо сделать так чтоб при открытии первой вьюшки, при определённой переменной в модели поступающей из контроллера при её запуске, открывалось сразу всплывающее окно будто нажали кнопку.

Как это можно сделать?

Почти уверен, что как-то очень быстро. но увы я не шарю в js

Comment: Писать веб приложения под браузер и не шарить в JS - это тяжко.

Answer (score 0):

Так как у Вас в вопросе нет кода - постараюсь ответить словами:

Вы пишете:

"при определённой переменной в моделе поступающей из контроллера при её запуске" - значит, где то в JS коде у Вас есть блок кода, запрашивающий данные.

Добавляем туда проверку значения той самой переменной, при определенном значении которой должно открываться всплывающее окно.

Если условие выполнилось - открываем окно из JS любым удобным способом. Либо из нативного JS, либо через jquery. Обычно открыте окна сводится к тому, чтобы убрать ему свойство "hide = true"